# How do I copy a text code from a PDF and paste into centos Virtual Machine Gedit

Tags: gedit

Im trying to copy this code from a pdf and paste it into VM Gedit:

Why a simple Control C and Control V wont work!?

Thanks for the help!

```
records = LOAD '2013_subset.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
(Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,\
CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,\
CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,\
Distance:int,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,\
Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,\
LateAircraftDelay);
milage_recs = GROUP records ALL;
tot_miles = FOREACH milage_recs GENERATE SUM(records.Distance);
STORE tot_miles INTO /user/root/totalmiles;
```

Comment: If you're using VirtualBox for your VM, make sure you have `Shared Clipboard` set to Bidirectional under Devices menu.  Usually after setting that you have to restart the VM.

Comment: Im using Centos virutal Machine... Any idea?

Comment: @SimonGIS What are the host OS, guest OS, and hypervisor?

Comment: Centos as Guest OS / VMware host OS  / Hypervisor? Im not sure what it is... Im new to this! Thanks for your help!

Comment: VMWare is the hypervisor, so then what is the host OS?

Comment: @SimonGIS Wikipedia has a good explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization#Hardware_virtualization

Comment: Im following this Hadoop tutorial: http://javaarm.com/file/apache/Hadoop/books/Hadoop-for-dumies_Dirk.deRoos-Paul.C_2014.pdf... I follow the instructions until page 64... Maybe this will help more? thanks

Comment: @SimonGIS I have never worked with Hadoop, but if this is the only reason of you setting up a VM, you can easier the task to yourself by simply doing everything on your Ubuntu host. CentOS instructions with little modifications would fit very well on any distro. As for the question — try perhaps installing guest extensions.